# Does SigningCertURL of AWS SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I have to whitelist urls used in my application.
AWS SNS notification messages contains few urls like signing, subscribe, unscubscribe.
So I need to check whether or not AWS sns SigningCertURL changes if there is infra change, if sns get deployed again?